# Uncaught ReferenceError: pagespeed is not defined at HTMLImageElement.onload (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have some problem with errors in console, everything works fine but I get errors while loading content via ajax. Im using bootstrap and a modal element to load there images via ajax, and those images generate these errors - when I click a button. How to avoid such error?

> Uncaught ReferenceError: pagespeed is not defined
> at HTMLImageElement.onload ((index):1:1)

```
const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("modalImage").innerHTML = this.responseText;
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "include/image.php?id=" + id);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Thanks in advice

Comment: When you debug, what does `this.responseText` contain?  Does it include `<script>` elements which themselves are being executed and contain errors?

Comment: `pagespeed` doesn't occur anywhere in that tiny snippet of code you have shown us so far. And the error message says "at HTMLImageElement.onload", so it can't be directly referring to the load even handler you have shown us there, because that is for an XMLHttpRequest instance, which is not an HTMLImageElement. This needs more clarity, preferably a proper [mre].

Comment: the error raised in line 1 can you show the whole snippet? or at least a little more